# How Do I Only Initialize ONE Of My Class's Properties?

Tags: swift, binding, swiftui, option-type, forced-unwrapping

I have a class with three properties, `topic`, `navBarHidden` and `viewModel` and I need to initialize the viewmodel with one of the class's properties, `topic`.
But I don't need to initialize the other properties, ```topic. I have to initialize the view model because it makes a necessary API call.

Here's a snippet of the code.

```
struct TopicCell: View {
    @Binding var navBarHidden : Bool?
    @State var topic: Topic?
    @ObservedObject var viewModel : TopicCellViewModel
    
    init() {
        self.viewModel = TopicCellViewModel(topic: self.topic!)
    }
    
}
```

At first `topic` and `navBarHidden` weren't optionals, but then I'd have to initialize them, which I don't want to do. All the data that will initialize them needs to be passed in. So I made them optionals, which makes me not have to initialize them, then I just force unwrap the optionals.

But this gives me one issue.

```
NavigationLink( 
destination: DebateChatView(navBarHidden: $navBarHidden, topic: $topic, subtopic:
 .constant(SubTopic(dictionary: ["id": "", "topic": "Random Subtopic", "title": topic!.title, 
"bool": false , "messages": MOCK_MESSAGEZ])))
```

Notice the two binding variables, of `topic` and `navBarHidden`. These don't work now, because DebateChatView is expecting bound normal data, not bound optionals. But `$topic!` doesn't work. So, can someone please tell me the best way to fix this issue?

Comment: Making Boolean optional doesn't sounds nice. Boolean are either true or false. A binding bool will receive value from parent view, then why optional? You also made "Topic" optional and straight away forced unwrapped in initialiser, that's dangerous, No where have you provided it any value. Why not giving them default values?

Comment: @TusharSharma Topic needs to be passed in when i call TopicCell. So, it should not have a default value. navBarHidden is also supposed to be decided by the parent object, so it should not have a default value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said values are to be decided when they are passed by parent, you can `initialise` target view to accept those `parameters` and simply assign the values.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TopicCell: View {
    @Binding var navBarHidden : Bool
    @State var topic: Topic
    @ObservedObject var viewModel : TopicCellViewModel
    
    init(topic:Topic,barHidden:Binding<Bool>) {
        _navBarHidden = barHidden
        _topic = State(wrappedValue: topic)
        self.viewModel = TopicCellViewModel(topic:topic)
    }
    
    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
            ForEach(0..<5) { index in
               
                    // Some stuff
               
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CellView:View {
    @State var isBarHidden = false
    
    var body: some View{
        TopicCell(topic: Topic(name: "someName"), barHidden: $isBarHidden)
    }
}

struct Topic{
    var name:String
}

class TopicCellViewModel:ObservableObject{
    var topic:Topic
    
    init(topic:Topic) {
        self.topic = topic
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is completely correct, this is the solution I found myself. How did you learn these things, such as `_topic, and State(wrappedValue)? I only came across these with random google searches, and that is not a time efficient way for me to complete this project. So I am asking where I can learn all of those specific tricks like initialize with underscore and State(wrappedValue) so I can know them

Comment: @CaylandBoston You can take out 15 min, and google into what happens when you write State or any other property wrapper to  a variable.

Comment: Taking 15 minutes to google every single issue is a pretty time inefficient way to learn how to program, I figured you learned it a better way